# Pass a value back from a Window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application.

I am creating a new window like so whenever a button is pressed:

```
MyWindow myWin = new MyWindow();
myWin.Show();
```

And then in the constructor of MyWindow I'm setting its parent to the main Application like so:

```
  public MyWindow ()
  {
     InitializeComponent();

     this.Owner = App.Current.MainWindow;
   }
```

This enables the window to not appear as a separate window and stays in front of my application.

Now I want to pass a parameter back from MyWindow whenever it closes.  How do I do this?  Something like this:

```
string myValue = myWin.Value.
```

Can this be done in WPF?

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't just be using `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()`?  That would let you use the window as a dialog to fetch values, which sounds like a better fit...

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't need to be a `WPF` specific solution to this... Really you have a `class` that can have a `public property` that the original class can access.

Now, if you would like a "fancy" solution... You could have a `TPL` solution (assuming you are using .NET 4.5).

You could do something like

```
public class MyWindow
{
  private TaskCompletionSource<String> _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<String>();

  public Task<String> Fetch()
  {
    return _tcs.Task;
  }

  public void handleButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    _tcs.SetResult("some value");
  }
}

...

var window = new MyWindow();
window.Show();

var value = await window.Fetch()
```

Answer (score 2):

change your code with this

```
MyWindow myWin = new MyWindow();
 myWin.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Keep in mind... When you use `ShowDialog()`, it will block the other windows... So if you have the idea of using multiple windows at the same time, this won't work too well.

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this

```
    public class Window1 : Window
{
    ...

    private void btnPromptFoo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var w = new Window2();
        if (w.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            string foo = w.Foo;
            ...
        }
    }
}

public class Window2 : Window
{
    ...

    public string Foo
    {
        get { return txtFoo.Text; }
    }

}
```

Comment: The question has already been answered, and more succinctly than your answer, which admittedly is correct.